# How to convert string into char * array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have changed my code, now while the compilation these errors occur:

```
`check.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`
```

`check.cpp:14:55: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’ [-fpermissive]`

`/usr/include/getopt.h:152:12: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int getopt(int, char* const*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]`

```
int main() {

string text="-f  input.gmn -output.jpg";
int argc=text.length();
cout<<"argc: "<<argc<<endl;
char const * argv = text.c_str();
cout<<"argv: "<<argv<<endl;
int c = getopt (argc, &argv, "f:s:o:pw:h:z:t:d:a:b:?");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `text.c_str()` to convert a `std::string` into a `const char*`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

To elaborate on my answer, there are many ways to create the array you need, but this is already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53849/589206), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/589206), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2727749/589206) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347949/589206). A simple solution to your problem that does not involve `new`/`malloc` or intensive uses of the STL and `istringstream`/`back_inserter`/`copy` what not and performs really fast could look like this:

```
/* variables. */
std::vector< char* > argv;
int i, argc, state;
char c;

/* convert string to char string with automatic garbage collection. */
std::vector< char > tokens(text.begin(), text.end());
tokens.push_back(0);

/* tokenize string with space. */
for (state=0, argc=0, i=0; (c=tokens[i]); i++) {
    if (state) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            tokens[i]=0;    
            state=0;        
        }           
    } else {
        if (c != ' ') {
            argv.push_back(&tokens[i]);
            argc++;         
            state=1;        
        }           
    }       
}   

/* print argv. */
std::cout << "argc: " << argc << std::endl;
for (i=0; i < argc; i++) {
    std::cout << "argv[" << i << "]: " << argv[i] << std::endl;
}   

/* call getopt. */
c = getopt(argc, &argv[0], "f:s:o:pw:h:z:t:d:a:b:?");
```

This is just an example, but one advantage of this kind of code is that you can use other characters as delimiter, not just space, and that you need not care about releasing the allocated memory since `std::vector` does this for you on function exit.

Comment: A `const char*` is not what is needed.  OP needs a `const char*[]`.  Multiple strings.

Comment: I added working code that solves the problem. Might be more elegant but covers all corner cases I could think up.

Answer (score 4):

First bug with your code is the comparison:

```
for (int i=0; i<=stringLength; i++) {
   arv[i]=text[i]; 
}
```

Use `i< stringLength` instead of `i<=stringLength`.

The second bug is that `arv` is not null-terminated.

After fixing both bugs, your code should look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < stringLength; i++) {
   arv[i]=text[i]; 
}
arv[stringLength] = '\0';
```

---

By the way, the [*correct* function signature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html) of `getopt` is this:

```
int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

which takes second and third argument as `const`. That means, you can do this:

```
 char const * s = text.c_str();
 int c = getopt (argc, &s, "f:s:o:pw:h:z:t:d:a:b:?");
```

No need of any conversion, using manual loop.

Answer (score 4):

In short, you have an array argv which contains 100 pointers to strings, of which only the first is set. argv[1] hasn't been set to anything, so is pointing somewhere random. And in this case, illegal.

Moreoever, what getoption expects is going to be more like this:

```
argv[0] = "progname";
argv[1] = "-f";
argv[2] = "input.gmn"
argv[3] = "-output.jpg"
argv[4] = 0
```

Note the =0 at the end to stop getoption chargins through random bits of memory