# Split string in C++

Tags: c++, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)
>   [C++ split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727749/c-split-string)

How I can split a line, shown below, in C++ from a file?

I want to save the result of game  output that has the following format:

```
CFC 1 - 0 RES
```

I have four variables:

```
string team1;
string team2;
int goalst1;
int goalst2;
```

How can I split the string so that each corresponding part is in the above four variables?

Comment: @Drise how to split a string using the format provided above. Team1 goalst1 - goalst2 team2.

Comment: Ironically, you just answered your own question.

Comment: Why do people not mention std::string::find(..) and std::string::substr(..)? Straightforward sln IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string team1;
string team2;
int goalst1;
int goalst2;
string dash;
std::cin >> team1 >> goalst1 >> dash >> goalst2 >> team2;
```

Comment: The input is not standard input. Is a line read from a file using getline function, which is stored in a variable of type string, I want to know how to split the string in order to have these values ​​in the variables

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this which requires `#include <sstream>`:

```
char trash;

std::stringstream mystream(myInputString);

mystream >> team1 >> goalst1 >> trash>> goalst2 >> team2;
```

or

```
char trash;

std::stringstream mystream;
mystream << myInputString;

mystream >> team1 >> goalst1 >> trash>> goalst2 >> team2;
```

Edit: This is more advanced but kinda neat. Stick this in a header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e(&sliteral)[N]) {
        std::array<e, N-1> buffer; //get buffer
        in >> buffer[0]; //skips whitespace
        if (N>2)
                in.read(&buffer[1], N-2); //read the rest
        if (strncmp(&buffer[0], sliteral, N-1)) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
template<class e, class t>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e& cliteral) {
        e buffer;  //get buffer
        in >> buffer; //read data
        if (buffer != cliteral) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, e(&carray)[N]) {
        return std::operator>>(in, carray);
}
template<class e, class t, class a>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, a& obj) {
        return in >> obj; //read data
}
```

This allows you to do string literals in streams:

```
std::stringstream mystream(myInputString);

mystream >> team1 >> goalst1 >> '-' >> goalst2 >> team2;
```

or

```
std::stringstream mystream;
mystream << myInputString;

mystream >> team1 >> goalst1 >> '-' >> goalst2 >> team2;
```

See also: [Safer but easy-to-use and flexible C++ alternative to sscanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825768/safer-but-easy-to-use-and-flexible-c-alternative-to-sscanf#9832875)

Comment: The input is not standard input. Is a line read from a file using getline function, which is stored in a variable of type string, I want to know how to split the string in order to have these values ​​in the variables

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, u are probably trying to read from a file. Use ifstream then, and you can read from a file just like you read from a standard input like cin.

i.e.

```
  ifstream myfile("filename");
```

Now use myfile instead of cin operator and you are done..

Answer (score 0):

I like [`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp) for that kind of job:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

struct Result {
     std::string team1;
     std::string team2;
     unsigned goals1;
     unsigned goals2;
};

Result split(std::string const& s) {
    std::vector<std::string> splitted;
    boost::split(s, splitted, boost::token_compress_on);

    if (splitted.at(2) != "-") {
        throw runtime_error("The string format does not match");
    }

    Result r;
    r.team1 = splitted.at(0);
    r.team2 = splitted.at(4);
    r.goals1 = stoi(splitted.at(1));
    r.goals2 = stoi(splitted.at(3));

    return r;
}
```